# Why is my cursor so huge when using X11 forwarding?

Tags: linux, x11, xforwarding

I work on a Windows machine using Cygwin. Locally, my cursor renders just fine at the expected size:

[image]

But when I connect to my remote machine, the cursor is huge:

[image]

In this example I'm running xterm. The cursor change here is rendered by X; this is not my normal Windows cursor. I have the same problem when testing against CentOS 7 and Fedora 33.

Why is my cursor so huge and how can I fix it?

Comment: First thing to check is to use `xdpyinfo` both on your local machine and the remote machine, and see if there are differences, in particular for DPI. Second thing to check is font resolution (which is a bit of science), potentially your local cursor comes from a different font than the remote cursor.

Answer (score 5):

The cursor is large because the remote and local machines have different screen-resolutions.

You might notice that the glyph used for the *I-beam* cursor (actually ***xterm***) is different in the two screenshots.  That is because the image is loaded from the local machine when *cursor themes* are used, as a bitmap, rather than (per the original design of X) displaying a glyph whose attributes are known by the X server.

Most applications do not link directly to the Xcursor library which implements cursor-themes.
The [X11 library](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xcursor/xcursor.html#h3-Glyph-Cursor-APIs) supports cursor-themes by modifying the calls which create "font-cursors" or "glyph-cursors", and applications do not see this directly.

When xterm starts, if it was built in an environment where the Xcursor library was found, it "knows" that cursor-themes may be in use, and overrides the `XCURSOR_PATH` environment variable.  xterm patch #367 will be more configurable in this area (including the ability to select different cursor-themes), but the underlying problem is a design limitation of cursor-themes which will never be fully addressed.

As a workaround, you might be able to select a smaller glyph using the [`XCURSOR_SIZE`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xcursor/xcursor.html) environment variable (in the remote process which *starts* xterm):

> **`XCURSOR_SIZE`**
>
> This variable sets the desired cursor size, in pixels.
>
> If the environment variable is not given, *Xcursor*  tries
> the **`Xcursor.size`** resource.
>
> If  no size is given, whether by environment variable or
> resource  setting,  *Xcursor*  next  tries   the   Xft.dpi
> resource setting to guess the size of a 16-point cursor.
> Finally, if **`Xft.dpi`** is not set, *Xcursor* uses the display
> height, dividing by 48  (assuming  that  the  height  is
> 768).